# Multiline strings in Flutter *.arb files

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization, arb

I am internationalizing my flutter app.

I have some long paragraphs that need to be internationalised, and in the `.arb` file it becomes painful to scroll.

How can I break up the paragraph over multiple lines?

Answer (score 13):

I think this is not possible. (Please correct me someone if this is wrong!)

You could add `\n` to the String resource for line breaks if necessary. And to overcome the "painful scroll" I enabled soft wrap for all `*.arb` files.

**For Android Studio:**

1. Right click on row number inside any file
2. Configure Soft Wraps
3. Add `; *.arb` to entry "Soft-wrap these files", so my configuration looks like this:

```
*.md; *.txt; *.rst; *.adoc; *.arb
```

Compare [ApplicationResourceBundleSpecification](https://github.com/google/app-resource-bundle/wiki/ApplicationResourceBundleSpecification) for more information on ARB specification.

Answer (score 1):

I know i am a litle bit late but,

Yes, this is posible, a manage to do it using an VS Code extension call i18n arb editor

the proyect on github : https://github.com/thibault-vanderseypen/vsce-i18n-json-editor